# Powershell check a list of domain users status

Tags: powershell

I have a list of SamAccountName for domain users, I now need to check their status : exist, enabled or disabled. could not get it working well. the part for check `exist or not` works but `else` part wont. Where did I do wrong?

```
$users = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\log1.txt
foreach ($user in $users) {
$userobj = $(try {Get-ADUser $user} catch {$Null})


If ($userobj -eq $Null) {

    Write-Host "$user not exists" -foregroundcolor "red"

} else {
    $userstatus = get-ADUser $user | Select-Object -Property enabled

    if ( $userstatus = True) {Write-host "$user Enabled" -foregroundcolor "green"}

    else {write-host " $user Disabled" -foregroundcolor "yellow"}

}}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? I can't remember if `enabled` is part of the default properties returned. Why do you need to get the user twice when you already have `$userobj`? `$userstatus = get-ADUser $user | Select-Object -Property enabled` should be `$userstatus = get-ADUser $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty enabled`. `$userstatus = True` -> `$userstatus -eq $true` or just `if($userstatus)`. `$userobj = $(try {Get-ADUser $user} catch {$Null})` could just be `$userobj = Get-ADUser $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: What error are you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your condition for enabled users is not returning anything is because `Get-ADuser` does not get the `Enabled` property by default. You would need to specify it by using `-Properties Enabled` in your `Get-ADUser`

There are several ways you can compare your `testlist.txt` to ADUsers. When you use `Get-ADUser` if the account does not exist, it will not error. Instead it will just not return anything.

Instead of using a `try{}catch{}`, I would use a condition that checked the length of the results.

Also, you are already calling the `Get-ADUser` at the start of your `foreach{} loop`. There is no need to call it again further down: `$userstatus = get-ADUser $user | Select-Object -Property enabled`.

Here is a down and dirty way of checking if the user exists in AD then checking the status:

```
$importedList = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\log1.txt


foreach($object in $importedList)
{    
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $object} -Properties  SamAccountName, enabled | Select Samaccountname, enabled    

    if($user.Length -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host $object " does not exist" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $user
    }
}
```

I personally, would rather put it all together into `array`. This way I can use it later on if I wanted to. Example:

```
$importedList = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\log1.txt
$userResults = @() #define the empty array

foreach($object in $importedList)
{   

    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $object} -Properties SamAccountName, enabled | Select Samaccountname, enabled    

    if($user.Length -eq 0)
    {   
        $exists = $false
        $enabled = "NA"
    }
    else
    {
        $exists = $true
        $enabled = $user.Enabled
    }

    $userResult = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Account = $object
        Exists = $exists
        Enabled = $enabled
    }
    $userResults += $userResult
}

$userResults
```

This would allow you to do something like:

```
$userResults | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $true} #Get all enabled users
$userResults | Export-csv UserResults.Csv -NoTypeInformation #export to csv
```

Answer (score 1):

OK lets talk about the command you displayed. You have 2 issues

```
$userstatus = get-ADUser $user | Select-Object -Property enabled
```

this will bring back the Property and value of Enabled you should use **-ExpandProperty** to just get the value of the property

and then

```
if ( $userstatus = True)
```

= in powershell is -eq

```
$users = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\log1.txt
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userobj = $(
        try {
            Get-ADUser $user
        }catch{
            $Null
        }
    )
    If($userobj -eq $Null) {
        Write-Host "$user not exists" -foregroundcolor "red"
    }else{
        $userstatus = get-ADUser $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty enabled
        if ($userstatus -eq True){
            Write-host "$user Enabled" -foregroundcolor "green"
        }else{
            write-host " $user Disabled" -foregroundcolor "yellow"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what i came up with trying to do the same thing

```
Get-Content -Path C:\test\log1.txt | %{
    try{
        $user = $_
        $Status = Get-ADUser $_ -ErrorAction Ignore | Select-Object -ExpandProperty enabled
        If (!($Status)){
            Write-Host "$user Disabled" -foregroundcolor "yellow"
        }else{
            Write-Host "$user Enabled" -foregroundcolor "green"
        }
    }catch{
         Write-Host "$user not exists" -foregroundcolor "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: `$user = $_` is the key